# Visual Studio Error when Compiling - "Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpeHostx64.exe has stopped working"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to learn to code on my own having a ten year break since I coded in C and Java back in college. I downloaded Microsoft Visual Community on a brand new laptop, `i7 2GHZ, 12GB RAM, 512 SSD`. Upon compiling my first `C#` Hello World, from the `MVA C# Tutorial program`, I keep getting this error repeatedly, so much so that I get multiple instances of the Error window:

> "Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpeHostx64.exe has stopped working"
>   Debug | Click to Close

If I close the window, the window pops up again
If I click debug, Visual Studio opens up again and it requests to load Microsoft Symbols from an online library. It then rests in a steady state showing a project window identifying: Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpeHostx64 as a project.

How do I make this error go away?

Comment: Anything in the event log?

Comment: No nothing in the event log, it only appears when i try compiling a program in C#. I'm planning to uninstall MVS and reinstall a simpler version just to program in C#, C++ and Python.

Answer (score -1):

I am also experiencing this same problem with Visual Studio Community, trying to do a simple windows form application in Visual Basic. After I code the form and execute it, the build takes place and the single form displays on the screen. Then I receive the message you identified. Regardless of pressing debug or close, the error continues to pop up, even after I shut down Studio. To stop it, I must go to task manager and end the VSHub.Server process

Comment: this isn't an answer, you should use comments for this